# What is business object when choosing between ORM and Core in sqlalchemy?

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

The book *Essential SQLAlchemy* (Jason Myers, O'Reilly) gives a checklist to help decide which option to choose between, ORM or Core:

> • If you have data for which business objects are not needed, use Core.
>
> • If you view your data as business objects, use ORM.

But I don't know exactly what *business object* is. Of course, I even search Google but still can not understand. Need some specific example.

Comment: I take the term `business objects` to mean your code level objects, mapped with `business use cases`. IE, if you are a sales company, you might have a business object named `Sale`

Answer (score 2):

Core is simply an SQL abstraction toolkit which allows expression of the SQL language via generative Python expressions (basically writing literal SQL in Python).

ORM (which is built on top of Core) represents a higher level of abstraction. ORM is a technique that connects the rich objects of an application to tables in a relational database management system. Using ORM, the properties and relationships of the objects in an application can be easily stored and retrieved from a database without writing SQL statements directly and with less overall database access code.

Some of the ORM features include ability to define custom relationships; various design patterns such as associative proxy and adjacency lists; multiple types of table inheritance, etc.

In short: an ORM lets you work with (business) objects, obviating the need to construct lower level SQL.